# IOS app crash when memory usage is over 600M

Tags: ios, iphone, memory, crash

When the memory usage goes over 600M of my application crashes with a message

```
Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue
```

With out any stack trace.

I am using iPhone 6.

No issues when I am using simulator.

Comment: Don't use so much memory then, it's a constrained environment on the device

Comment: There are tools that can help you finding what is using memory. If you are using 600 MB, the surprise is not that your app gets terminated, the surprise is that it didn't get terminated earlier.

Comment: Try allocations instrument and see on which screen max memory is allocated and not freed. Please post some code if there is a crash on a particular screen.

Comment: It is a game. Images are heavy. The interesting thing that week before, application was working over 600M.